# Update elastic search nested field based on query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, update-by-query

I have an Elasticsearch index named `pollstat` with mapping as follows:

```
{
  "pollstat" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "dt" : {
          "properties" : {
            "dte" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "is_polled" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        "is_profiled" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "maid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above index is created using:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/pollstat" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "maid" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "dt" : {
        "type" : "object",
    "properties": {
        "dte" : {"type":"date"},
        "is_polled" : {"type":"boolean"}
    }
      },
      "is_profiled" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      }
    },
  "dynamic":false
  }

}'
```

To add data into this index, I am using the following code:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/pollstat/_doc/?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"maid" : "fans", "dt" : [{"dte": "2022-03-19", "is_polled":true } ], "is_profiled":true } '
```

**This is working.**

The requirement is to append the dt field when a particular maid polls data on a specific date.  In this case, if the maid `fans` polls data for another day, I want to append the same to the dt field.

I used the following code, which takes the document `id` to update the document.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/pollstat/_doc/hQh4oH8BPfXX63hBUbPN/_update?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"script": {"source": "ctx._source.dt.addAll(params.dt)", "params": {"dt": [{ "dte": "2019-07-16", "is_polled": true }, { "dte": "2019-07-17", "is_polled": false } ] } } } '
```

**This is also working**

However, my application does not have visibility to the document id but gets the maid.  The maid is also as unique as the document id.    Hence to update a specific maid, I was trying to do the same with a query on maid.

I used the following code:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/pollstat/_update_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'"query": {"match": { "maid": "fans" }, "script": {"source": "ctx._source.dt.addAll(params.dt)", "params": {"dt": [{ "dte": "2019-07-18", "is_polled": true }, { "dte": "2019-07-19", "is_polled": false } ] } } }'
```

This code executes without an error and I am getting the following update status as well:

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 1,
  "updated" : 1,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

However my index is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `maid` field has type `keyword`, I had to use the query->term instead of query->match.  The final query is as follows:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/pollstat/_update_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {    
         "term": { "maid": "fans" }},
        "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.dt.addAll(params.dt)",
        "params": {
            "dt": [
                { "dte": "2019-07-18", "is_polled": true },
                { "dte": "2019-07-19", "is_polled": false }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'
```

Posting this answer for others reference.